# Sharepoint 2010 practice tasks

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I use to work on MOSS 2007 and I recently migrated the site to sharepoint 2010 (without visual upgrade). I have access to test server and currently I am not having any technical tasks. I would like to know if there are any sites which posts tasks given by clients or practice development queries using sharepoint and Visual studio. I would like to understand and implement such tasks in my free time. So if any one can please suggest links for the same or even give me some task to perform for me to learn.

Answer (score 1):

I found the follow links very useful to learn about SharePoint 2010 and they include exercises to do as well, so you can improve your knowledge.

[SharePoint 2010 Developer Training Course](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg620703) (Download offline training course)

[Get Started Developing on SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee513147)

Enjoy!